# Getting error - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.info(String)"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to fix this error. Sharing my code. Please help

Getting error - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.info(String)" because the return value of "org.mdb.reports.ExtentManager.getExtentTest()" is null    at org.mdb.reports.ExtentLogger.info(ExtentLogger.java:31)  at org.mdb.scripts.Base.login(Base.ja

OpportunityCreationTest.java file

```
public class OpportunityCreationTest extends OpportunityBase {

    private OpportunityCreationTest (){

    }

    @DataProvider(name = "getOpportunityData", parallel = true)
    public Iterator<Object[]> getOpportunityData() {
        Collection<Object[]> mapObj = new ArrayList<>();
        for (HashMap<String, Object> map : JsonFileParser.getJsonData(JsonFileName.OPPORTUNITY)) {
            mapObj.add(new Object[]{map});
        }
        return mapObj.iterator();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "getOpportunityData", description = "Verify Sales Reps are able to create Opportunities", groups = {"test"})
    public void createOppTest(HashMap<String, Object> map) throws Exception {
        login();
        dataSetUp(map.get("url").toString(), map.get("sales_rep").toString());
        String closeDateValue = JsonFileParser.getJsonData(JsonFileName.OPPORTUNITY).get(0).get("closeDateValue").toString();

        createOpportunity(closeDateValue);
        logout();
    }
    }
```

Base.java

```
    public static void login() throws Exception {
        ExtentLogger.info("Launching " + PropertyUtils.getValue(ConfigProperties.ENVIRONMENT) + "url");
        DriverManager.getDriver().get(JsonUtils.getValue(ConfigProperties.URL));
        SalesforceLoginLogout salesforceLoginLogout = new SalesforceLoginLogout();
        try {
            salesforceLoginLogout.login();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Extendlogger.java

```
    public static void info(String message) {
      ExtentManager.getExtentTest().info(message);
    }
```

i dont want to update the base.java or Extendlogger.java. i want to fix OpportunityCreationTest.java file, what am i missing to pass?

Comment: Have you called `createNewExtentTest` anywhere prior?

Comment: No. if i comment below line from Base.java then it is working. but i dont want to do that.

        ExtentLogger.info("Launching " + PropertyUtils.getValue(ConfigProperties.ENVIRONMENT) + "url");